# Update ng-style based on JSON response

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-style

Trying to update the ng-style attribute for width based on the response that I get when the app first loads. Right now I am able to grab the data (count) that I need but I am trying to bind this count to a style of the progress as well.

Right now I have:

```
 <div class="bar-warning" ng-style="{width: 20+'%'}"></div>
 <div class="bar-success" ng-style="{width: 43+'%'}"></div>
```

Which is just static and I am showing the count using this:

```
<span class="submitCount">{{getTaskCount("VIEW")}}&nbsp;Complete</span>
<span class="reviewCount">{{getTaskCount("REVIEW")}}&nbsp;IN REVIEW</span>
<span class="todoCount">{{getTaskCount("PROVIDE") + getTaskCount("SIGN")}}&nbsp;TO DO</span></p>
```

So I want to try and do something like this:

```
<div class="bar-warning" ng-style="{width: {getTaskCount("VIEW")*10}+'%'}"></div>
```

So that I could get a width of something like 32% or 58% which would be used to adjust the css width property.

There's a lot of functionality bound to this so too much to fiddle just wondering if anyone has a good solution for updating ng-style like this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your quotes and braces look wrong. How about `ng-style="{width: getTaskCount('VIEW') * 10 + '%'}"`. You can also just use `style="width: {{getTaskCount('VIEW') * 10}}%"`

Comment: That actually worked pretty good. Thanks. Now just gotta factor the equation and figure out how to get the third span added together for the two different counts. Thanks man.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil Please put in the answer so I can give you credit. I'll have to factor out an equation but that got me past the first part. Thanks again.